# Pygame Error AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

Tags: collision-detection, sprites, python, pygame

I'm making my first game of Pygame. I'm going to create groups for making collisions but when I add an object to the group, I get an error in sprite.py (Pygame's Files)

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'add_internal'
```

Why I get this error?
There is a simplest way to make collisions?

There is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import os
import time
width = 950
height = 500
Game = False
GameOver = False
keyboard = pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Dog')
    background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Background_00.png")).convert()
    FlappyDog = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Flappy.png")).convert_alpha()
    Play = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Play.png")).convert_alpha()
    Dog0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Dog0.png")).convert_alpha()
    Dog1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Dog1.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeUp0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeUp0.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeUp1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeUp1.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeDown0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeDown0.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeDown1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeDown1.png")).convert_alpha()
    GameOver = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Game-Over.png")).convert_alpha()
    Replay = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Replay.png")).convert_alpha()
    Bone = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Bone.png")).convert_alpha()

    Game = True
    Dog1_pos_x = 100
    Dog1_pos_y = 100
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(FlappyDog, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(Bone, (550, 100))
    screen.blit(Play, (600, 350))
    screen.blit(Dog0, (5, 240))
    bones = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bones.add(Bone) # <-- Error here
    Dog = pygame.sprite.Group()
    Dog.add(Dog1)
    pygame.display.update()


    while True:
        if GameOver == true:
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(GameOver, (20, 50))
        if pygame.sprite.gropucollide(Dog, Bones, True, True):
            Game = False
            GameOver = True
        while Game == True:
            pygame.event.pump()
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
                for i in range(10): # Up
                    Dog1_pos_y = Dog1_pos_y -1
                    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
                    screen.blit(Dog1, (Dog1_pos_x, Dog1_pos_y))
                    screen.blit(SpikeDown0, (0, 436))
                    screen.blit(SpikeUp0, (0, 0))
                    pygame.display.update()
                    pygame.time.delay(1)
            else: # Down
                Dog1_pos_y = Dog1_pos_y +1
                screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
                screen.blit(Dog1, (Dog1_pos_x, Dog1_pos_y))
                screen.blit(SpikeDown0, (0, 436))
                screen.blit(SpikeUp0, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
                pygame.time.delay(1)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                pygame.display.update()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you search for [existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37057027/3064164) discussing [similar errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48039832/3064164)? How have you tried applying these existing answers to your case?

Comment: Yes, In the first URL, in the code that is "fine", i'ts exactly the same, only that change the object name. I don't know why I obtain the error.

Comment: So, like in the answer at the first link, you tried creating a Sprite object to add each image to, then add your sprites to the group? Where did this go wrong for you?

Comment: I dont know. Pygame says that the error is here `bonesSpikes.add (SpikeDown0)` and in a pygame file (Sprite.py)

Comment: Right, because `SpikeDown0` is a `Surface`, and you're trying to add it to a group made to contain `Sprite` objects. Did you follow the linked answer and try something like `SpikeDown0Sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()` `SpikeDown0Sprite.image = SpikeDown0` ... `boneSpikes.add(SpikeDown0Sprite)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming languages like Python have types, which determine what you can do with which piece of data. Using each variable in a way that's appropriate to its type is like putting a round peg in a round hole, or a square peg into a square hole.

When you try to do an operation that expects one type, but you give it a different, incompatible type, that's trying to shove a square peg into a round hole. The computer won't be able to make sense of the operation and it will throw an error.

That's what you have happening here. `bones = pygame.sprite.Group()` tells the computer "`bones` is a group that holds `Sprite` objects" (ie. it's a round hole to put round pegs into)

`Bone = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Bone.png")).convert_alpha()` tells the computer "`Bone` is a `Surface` object loaded from an image like so..." (ie. it's a square peg to put into a square hole)

`bones.add(Bone)` says "take that square peg (`Surface`) and shove it into that round hole (group of `Sprite` objects)"

So the computer errors-out and tells you that the `Bone` variable's type, `pygame.Surface`, does not have the shape that the `bones` variable's type, `pygame.sprite.Group` needs for its `add` method. It wants a `Sprite` that has an `add_internal` attribute, but you gave it a `Surface` which doesn't have that attribute.

> AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

So, first you need to make `Sprite` objects from the `Surface` objects you loaded from your images - think of it like an adapter to turn the square peg into a round peg -  like so:

```
boneSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
boneSprite.image = Bone
boneSprite.rect = Bone.get_rect()
```

Now that you have a `Sprite` that uses the `Bone` image, you can add it to your group like so:

```
bones.add(boneSprite)
```

This will not generate errors, because we're putting a round peg into a round hole now.

As described in the comments, [this is all explained in existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058274/3064164), so please take the time to search for existing documentation and read it thoroughly to solve your problems faster in future.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But now says that `'Sprite' Object has no attribute 'get_rect'`

Comment: What exact line is throwing the error?

Comment: The line that produces the error is `Bone.rect = Bone.image.get_rect()`

Comment: You're mixing types again. See how the object on the left in my example is called `boneSprite`? That's to help you keep track of the fact that it's a sprite, not the original `Bone` surface. You want something that looks like `(some Sprite).rect = (some Surface).get_rect()`. See how the object on the left and object on the right are two different types? So you can't use the same `Bone` variable in both places.

Comment: Ok, but now how can I blit it to the screen. Because says that I can't blit and sprite. Sorry for inconvenences

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than the one you originally asked. If you've already tried [searching for existing guides on the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=blit+image+pygame) and following them carefully & thoroughly, and still find yourself stuck, then you can post a new question showing what you've done and where you need help.